# How to get user's First and Last Name from SSO login?

Tags: authentication, single-sign-on, oracle-apex, oracle-xe

I am using a Oracle SSO server to authenticate users of my APEX app. I wish to display user's first name and last name on my app, I don't want to ask the users for this info. How can I get this info from SSO server ? Do I have to read cookies?

Answer (score 0):

When using SSO, this information is typically passed in to your application through a custom header. You should be able to configure the SSO provider to pass the user name back to your application through the header, and the client side of your application should have an API for withdrawing it from there.

Answer (score 0):

It depends how your Identity Provider (IP) is configured - in our case, the encrypted artifact passed to our application (via a cookie in our case, but could be passed in the querystring or posted to your app) contains the information about the logged in user that our IP has configured to send to us.